# Adding empty rows to Angular Material table when rows are less than a set number?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I have two angular tables and I am comparing their data side by side, let's say I have default 10 rows to show up on both tables, It can be the case that either if the two tables has less than 10 rows. E.g One table has 10 rows and second has just 1, so the second table end at just 1 row, what I would like to do is to have some empty rows(Number of rows that should be present - number of rows actually present). How can I do that ?

My First table

`test-table.component.html`

```js
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <table mat-table class="full-width-table" matSort aria-label="Elements">
    <!-- Id Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Id</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.id}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Name</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.name}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>

  <mat-paginator #paginator
      [length]="dataSource?.data.length"
      [pageIndex]="0"
      [pageSize]="50"
      [pageSizeOptions]="[25, 50, 100, 250]">
  </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

Data source file for this

`test-table-datasource.ts`

```js
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, of as observableOf, merge } from 'rxjs';

// TODO: Replace this with your own data model type
export interface TestTableItem {
  name: string;
  id: number;
}

// TODO: replace this with real data from your application
const EXAMPLE_DATA: TestTableItem[] = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Hydrogen'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Helium'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Lithium'},
  {id: 4, name: 'Beryllium'},
  {id: 5, name: 'Boron'},
  {id: 6, name: 'Carbon'},
  {id: 7, name: 'Nitrogen'},
  {id: 8, name: 'Oxygen'},
  {id: 9, name: 'Fluorine'},
  {id: 10, name: 'Neon'},
  {id: 11, name: 'Sodium'},
  {id: 12, name: 'Magnesium'},
  {id: 13, name: 'Aluminum'},
  {id: 14, name: 'Silicon'},
  {id: 15, name: 'Phosphorus'},
  {id: 16, name: 'Sulfur'},
  {id: 17, name: 'Chlorine'},
  {id: 18, name: 'Argon'},
  {id: 19, name: 'Potassium'},
  {id: 20, name: 'Calcium'},
];

/**
 * Data source for the TestTable view. This class should
 * encapsulate all logic for fetching and manipulating the displayed data
 * (including sorting, pagination, and filtering).
 */
export class TestTableDataSource extends DataSource<TestTableItem> {
  data: TestTableItem[] = EXAMPLE_DATA;
  paginator: MatPaginator;
  sort: MatSort;

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  /**
   * Connect this data source to the table. The table will only update when
   * the returned stream emits new items.
   * @returns A stream of the items to be rendered.
   */
  connect(): Observable<TestTableItem[]> {
    // Combine everything that affects the rendered data into one update
    // stream for the data-table to consume.
    const dataMutations = [
      observableOf(this.data),
      this.paginator.page,
      this.sort.sortChange
    ];

    return merge(...dataMutations).pipe(map(() => {
      return this.getPagedData(this.getSortedData([...this.data]));
    }));
  }

  /**
   *  Called when the table is being destroyed. Use this function, to clean up
   * any open connections or free any held resources that were set up during connect.
   */
  disconnect() {}

  /**
   * Paginate the data (client-side). If you're using server-side pagination,
   * this would be replaced by requesting the appropriate data from the server.
   */
  private getPagedData(data: TestTableItem[]) {
    const startIndex = this.paginator.pageIndex * this.paginator.pageSize;
    return data.splice(startIndex, this.paginator.pageSize);
  }

  /**
   * Sort the data (client-side). If you're using server-side sorting,
   * this would be replaced by requesting the appropriate data from the server.
   */
  private getSortedData(data: TestTableItem[]) {
    if (!this.sort.active || this.sort.direction === '') {
      return data;
    }

    return data.sort((a, b) => {
      const isAsc = this.sort.direction === 'asc';
      switch (this.sort.active) {
        case 'name': return compare(a.name, b.name, isAsc);
        case 'id': return compare(+a.id, +b.id, isAsc);
        default: return 0;
      }
    });
  }
}

/** Simple sort comparator for example ID/Name columns (for client-side sorting). */
function compare(a: string | number, b: string | number, isAsc: boolean) {
  return (a < b ? -1 : 1) * (isAsc ? 1 : -1);
}
```

`test-table.component.ts`

```js
import { AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTable } from '@angular/material/table';
import { TestTableDataSource, TestTableItem } from './test-table-datasource';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-table',
  templateUrl: './test-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test-table.component.css']
})
export class TestTableComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatTable) table: MatTable<TestTableItem>;
  dataSource: TestTableDataSource;

  /** Columns displayed in the table. Columns IDs can be added, removed, or reordered. */
  displayedColumns = ['id', 'name'];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource = new TestTableDataSource();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.table.dataSource = this.dataSource;
  }
}
```

My Second Table
`sample-table.component.html`

```js
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <table mat-table class="full-width-table" matSort aria-label="Elements">
    <!-- Id Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Id</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.id}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Name</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.name}}</td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>

  <mat-paginator #paginator
      [length]="dataSource?.data.length"
      [pageIndex]="0"
      [pageSize]="50"
      [pageSizeOptions]="[25, 50, 100, 250]">
  </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

`sample-table-datasource.ts`

```js
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, of as observableOf, merge } from 'rxjs';

// TODO: Replace this with your own data model type
export interface SampleTableItem {
  name: string;
  id: number;
}

// TODO: replace this with real data from your application
const EXAMPLE_DATA: SampleTableItem[] = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Hydrogen'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Helium'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Lithium'},
  {id: 4, name: 'Beryllium'},
  {id: 5, name: 'Boron'},
  {id: 6, name: 'Carbon'},
  {id: 7, name: 'Nitrogen'},
  {id: 8, name: 'Oxygen'},
  {id: 9, name: 'Fluorine'},
  {id: 10, name: 'Neon'},
  {id: 11, name: 'Sodium'},
  {id: 12, name: 'Magnesium'},
  {id: 13, name: 'Aluminum'},
  {id: 14, name: 'Silicon'},
  {id: 15, name: 'Phosphorus'},
  {id: 16, name: 'Sulfur'},
  {id: 17, name: 'Chlorine'},
  {id: 18, name: 'Argon'},
  {id: 19, name: 'Potassium'},
  {id: 20, name: 'Calcium'},
];

/**
 * Data source for the SampleTable view. This class should
 * encapsulate all logic for fetching and manipulating the displayed data
 * (including sorting, pagination, and filtering).
 */
export class SampleTableDataSource extends DataSource<SampleTableItem> {
  data: SampleTableItem[] = EXAMPLE_DATA;
  paginator: MatPaginator;
  sort: MatSort;

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  /**
   * Connect this data source to the table. The table will only update when
   * the returned stream emits new items.
   * @returns A stream of the items to be rendered.
   */
  connect(): Observable<SampleTableItem[]> {
    // Combine everything that affects the rendered data into one update
    // stream for the data-table to consume.
    const dataMutations = [
      observableOf(this.data),
      this.paginator.page,
      this.sort.sortChange
    ];

    return merge(...dataMutations).pipe(map(() => {
      return this.getPagedData(this.getSortedData([...this.data]));
    }));
  }

  /**
   *  Called when the table is being destroyed. Use this function, to clean up
   * any open connections or free any held resources that were set up during connect.
   */
  disconnect() {}

  /**
   * Paginate the data (client-side). If you're using server-side pagination,
   * this would be replaced by requesting the appropriate data from the server.
   */
  private getPagedData(data: SampleTableItem[]) {
    const startIndex = this.paginator.pageIndex * this.paginator.pageSize;
    return data.splice(startIndex, this.paginator.pageSize);
  }

  /**
   * Sort the data (client-side). If you're using server-side sorting,
   * this would be replaced by requesting the appropriate data from the server.
   */
  private getSortedData(data: SampleTableItem[]) {
    if (!this.sort.active || this.sort.direction === '') {
      return data;
    }

    return data.sort((a, b) => {
      const isAsc = this.sort.direction === 'asc';
      switch (this.sort.active) {
        case 'name': return compare(a.name, b.name, isAsc);
        case 'id': return compare(+a.id, +b.id, isAsc);
        default: return 0;
      }
    });
  }
}

/** Simple sort comparator for example ID/Name columns (for client-side sorting). */
function compare(a: string | number, b: string | number, isAsc: boolean) {
  return (a < b ? -1 : 1) * (isAsc ? 1 : -1);
}
```

`sample-table.component.ts`

```js
import { AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTable } from '@angular/material/table';
import { SampleTableDataSource, SampleTableItem } from './sample-table-datasource';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sample-table',
  templateUrl: './sample-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sample-table.component.css']
})
export class SampleTableComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatTable) table: MatTable<SampleTableItem>;
  dataSource: SampleTableDataSource;

  /** Columns displayed in the table. Columns IDs can be added, removed, or reordered. */
  displayedColumns = ['id', 'name'];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource = new SampleTableDataSource();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.table.dataSource = this.dataSource;
  }
}
```

`app-compoenent.html`

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
<h3>Table 1</h3>
<app-test-table></app-test-table>
</div>    
<div class="col">
<h3>Table 2 </h3>
<app-sample-table></app-sample-table>
</div>
</div>
```

How do I add empty rows dynamically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I have figured it out, here's the correct answer

In `test-table-datasource.ts`
Add the following to `getPagedData` method

```js
 private getPagedData(data: TestTableItem[]) {
    const startIndex = this.paginator.pageIndex * this.paginator.pageSize;
    if( data.length -  startIndex < this.paginator.pageSize ){
      let diff = this.paginator.pageSize -(data.length - startIndex)
      for(let i=0 ; i<diff;i++){
        data.push(Object.create(null));
      }
    }

    return data.splice(startIndex, this.paginator.pageSize);
  }
```

This will add the empty rows to the DataSource,and this actually doesn't permanently change your data, since it adds the empty rows according to the pageSize.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use `<mat-table>` instead of `<table>`, we could denote the data source like `<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">` and insert empty objects to it. Try the following

Controller

```js
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.inputData);
const length = 10 - this.dataSource._data._value.length;
for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  this.dataSource._data._value.push(Object.create(null));
}
```

Template

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="full-width-table" matSort aria-label="Elements">
    ...

  </mat-table>
  ...
</div>
```

I've used constant `10` to show the behavior. To synchronize actual lengths between two components, you could setup a singleton service that allows data passage b/n the child components.

Comment: Actually i am quite new to Angular and I am generating the table through CLI, so it creates the dataSource class for me by itself, I have added it in my answer now, can you look up and suggest the correct solution.Also One case could be that 1 table has 10 and other has 11 items, and when I go on the next page, I will have only 1 row there whereas I would like to have 10, and I am not sharing the Page Length size between the pages, what I want is, if I select to show 10 rows, and only x are present, I should see 10 -x rows.